# VS 2010 Express - Web - Very slow in debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have got a pretty good config machine and VS 2010 Web Express edition debugging is very slow. it gets stuck between lines. I dont face this issue with Visual studio 2010 prof edition.

Any hotfix or patches or solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem in VS 2008. Deleting(not disable) all breakpoints and restarting the debug session helped me get back to normal debugging.

You can give it a try.

Comment: Confirmed, deleting all breakpoints worked for me also. Strange.